# passing data back to calling function of async request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I read this answer on [returning data from async requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I am still having difficulty determining how to apply these answers in my application.

In the code below, I am trying to access the returned result of the getWeather async request and use that data in the jsx that follows in the return statement below getWeather.

I noticed the answers to the previous OP's question said to handle the results in a callback function, but I don't know how to get that passed back up the chain as a result of the getWeather call.

My question - how can I pass this data back and access it inside of the FiveDayWeather function?

```
const URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=94040&appid=${OPEN_WEATHER_KEY}`

const FiveDayWeather = () => {
  let days = getWeather()

  return(
    <div className="five-day-weather">
      <div className="day-of-week-item">
        <div className="day">Hi Again</div>
        <div className="image-indicator"></div>
        <div className="temp"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function getWeather() {
  axios.get(URL)
    .then(function(response) {
      handleData(response)
    })
}

function handleData(response) {
  return response
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be making the API call in `componentDidMount` method and set the result in the `state` of the component. Then in your render method, you need to use `state`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      days: []
    };

  }

getWeather() {
  axios.get(URL)
    .then(response => {
       this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           days: response //Set the right value here from response
       });
    }).catch( error => {
       this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           error
       }); 
    });
 }

render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, days } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        // your template to show the data goes here
      );
    }
  }
```

Refer to the ReactJS docs for AJAX [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html).

Comment: This won't work. The function inside `axios.get(URL).then()` is not binded to the component, so it cannot access the `this.setState()`

Comment: Updated to use Arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getWeather()` isn't returning something, and the `handleData()` is not doing what you think.

Instead of lots of returns, you should try a `async` function. The `axios` works asynchronously. So, the `await` will wait until the data is retrieved from axios, an then return it. Try like this:

```
async function getWeather() {
 return await axios.get(URL)
}
```

Comment: That won't work either, it'll return an empty object!